# Download XML feed to local disk

Tags: xml

I want to download automatically a `XML` feed which is placed on a server to my PC or alternatively to `Google Drive` (or something like this).

I can access this file via a specific URL which changes every day (Generated by URL & (Username + Password + Date encrypted by `SHA-1`)).

I'm a newbie so if you have any solutions for my problem, it would be nice if you could explain it in easy way or give references so I can learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to learn two things:

1. How to make a web request and read the response
2. How to write a string to a file